# Replace shutdown with hibernate

Tags: windows, winapi, shutdown

**Tl;dr**: Is it possible to catch system shutdown messages (and alter/remove them) *before* they are being processed?

---

### Preliminary

I am working on a cluster management software. Right now, **idle machines in the cluster are being shut down by a third party software**. In the environment my software is tested with, it is not acceptable to lose a lot of time on shutting down, booting up and starting all the programs. As a result, the point at which a machine is considered to be *idle* has been set to something like 3 hours. This is not really *"power saving"*.
The idea is to **replace the systems shutdown message with a hibernate message**.
The OS is Windows XP but an update to **Windows 7** is planned. So ideally, the solution should work on both.

### Ideas so far

- **Replace `shutdown.exe`**
  This is how I did it with the UNIX clients. However, I don't think that common Windows applications just calls `exec()` on `shutdown.exe` to get the system to shut down. Instead, they probably call `ExitWindowsEx()`. I want to catch the messages resulting from this call as well.
- **Handling `WM_QUERYENDSESSION`**
  This is not a solution, either, for two reasons:

  - This message is delivered to all running programs in an *unpredictable* order. Even if I cancel the shutdown by returning `FALSE`, some programs might have gotten the message earlier and exited already.
  - Since Vista, returning `FALSE` does not result in a silent cancellation of the shutdown. Instead, the whole screen is blocked and the user is informed about the program(s) blocking the shutdown. So even if I manage to go into hibernate at this point, at the next startup the whole screen is blocked.

  Especially the first point is crucial. I can only justify shutting down the machines if it doesn't cost precious time. Not having to restart the programs when returning from hibernate is a big part of that.
- **`SetWindowsHookEx()`**
  I thought about hooks. However, this method seems quite painful, since [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) states, that I would have to deliver both my program and the DLL containing the hook in both flavors (x86_64 and x86). This is bound to fail.
  But let's assume I manage to get this to work, I cannot seem to catch the system's shutdown message *before* it's being dispatched to other windows, let alone alter or delete that message.

### Restrictions

There are basically no restrictions. Since the Windows running on those machine is being installed by myself, anything goes. If a hand-crafted mouse driver, which simulates mouse movement to click the *"Ok, don't shutdown"* button is the solution, so be it (another indicator, that I'm not trying to do evil ;) ). The more general the solution (e.g. being able to intercept and alter *any* message), the better!

Any hints and links (untested, experimental stuff) are appreciated.

Comment: The best option is to deal with this at source and stop the 3rd party program shutting down

Comment: This is an XY question.  Fix the X, shoot that 3rd party process in the head.

Comment: Do you know exactly how the third party software shuts down your workstations? Is it by `InitiateSystemShutdown`?

Comment: Well, the 3rd party software can only run as admin, so revoking it's rights for shutdown might be hard to do. I do **not** know how that program makes the machine shutdown. However, I am actually looking for an generic answer, so that if there are multiple 3rd party tools, I don't have to come up with a workaround for every single one of them.

Comment: you probably need to change the Registry to do it not sure about the specific code but look at Microsoft.com for code doing this will always set the server to hibernate instead of shut down but that means you can't shut it down at all unless you hold down the power button on the machine. you could also tell it to abort a shutdown completely. hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps you need to do to prevent the shutdown

1. Write a DLL that captures and redirects the ExitWindowsEx() function. You can accomplish this using [Microsoft Detours Library](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/detours/). Test this dll in your test process.
2. Once you have tested your dll, have that DLL load into every process by default using [AppInit_Dlls](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/197571/working-with-the-appinit-dlls-registry-value) registry value or use the utilities provided by detours package to selectively load the DLL into any process you want.
3. Write a process that uses one of the IPC mechanism to communicate with your DLL loaded in all the process to allow/deny/redirect the shutdown.